# plugins / alternatives to buggy input type="file"for images on cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

currently i'm using  on cordova projects in order to get a picture from camera or from android gallery.

the very same cordova project running on ios will offer me a gallery or camera.

the same html document on google chrome or any other android browser will offer camera or image gallery

i am searching out, however with no luck, a solution or even an alternative for android targets.

already tried [cordova plugin camera](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) but it isn't working.

i'm using cordova 6.3.1 and android platform 5.2.2

Comment: You have to use camera plugin to take the picture and file transfer plugin to submit it to the server, so you can provide more information about what isn't working when you tried the camera plugin

Comment: hey @jcesarmobile thanks for the answer. i'll assemble a smaller project in order to sample my situation.